# html form not holding it's elements' attributes when being passed from web page to child iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have a form that gets completed on a webpage by the user,
when the user submits the form, I bring up a bootstrap modal dialog, this dialog has an iframe in it that loads the form from the parent window calling a function in it like so:

```
//parent window
var formToSubmit;
function getForm(){
   return formToSubmit;
}

$("#submitButton").click(function(){
   //alterations to the elements in $("mainForm")

   formToSubmit = $("mainForm");
   $("#modalDialog").modal();
   //...
});

//modal iframe
var parentForm = parent.window.getForm();
$("#mainDiv").append(parentForm[0].outerHTML);
$("form").submit(function(){
   parent.window.closeModalWindow(); //not sure whether this will close AFTER the form is completely submitted yet

});

$("form").submit();
```

My problem is that I'm submitting these forms to microsoft sql server reporting services and  it takes every input element as a parameter. I have no control over this.

So when the user clicks submit in the main form, I disable all the elements that must not be set as parameters, the thing is; as soon as I get the form from the parent window and append it to the modal iframe, it seems as all of those changes are lost, is there any way to preserve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your problem likely has to do with the call to outerHTML on the form**. First of all, [implementations of outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) have been different across browsers, so I would avoid using it if possible. Second, outerHTML does not necessarily contain the live DOM element, but merely a dump of it as a string.

Therefore, I suggest deep cloning the form before passing it to your IFRAME.

With jQuery ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)):

`$("#mainDiv").append(parentForm.clone(true));`

Or plain JavaScript ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)):

`document.getElementByid('mainDiv').appendChild(parentForm[0].cloneNode(true));`

I ran some tests to verify this, and as long as you're cloning the form, you will get the results you're expecting.

---

As a side note, why are you duplicating the form in a modal? Are you re-creating it as a "please review" type thing for the user? It seems like a strange process. I only ask, because perhaps there are better ways to do what you're asking. Anyway, the answer I've given should help.

Comment: +1 taking the HTML source of a form field definitely won't include the current value (except sometimes in IE due to a bug). The `value="..."` attribute corresponds to the initial field value (`defaultValue` in DOM property terms) and not the current value. The current value is not reflected in any attribute. Cloning is the better thing to do, although in theory one ought to `importNode` rather than `cloneNode` when moving to a different document (with fallback for IE).

Comment: Nice work @bobince! I learned something new :) Thanks for contributing.

Comment: thanks, it's a long story;
the reason I'm recreating the form in the modal window is because the main page should be static and the user should be able to change just one selection after a report/result is returned from form submission.
I could have just done this with ajax, but when I had to show the modal window for feedback to the user. The thing is, the pdf would be downloaded and then I'm stuck with a moadl window that can't be closed by the user, because I didn't want the user to do multiple submits while the first/previous ones are still being processed.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a mess! But if you reach the goal, then so be it. Let us know if this gets you on your way, or if you need more help.

Comment: well, I'm . . .yup, it's working, don't worry was just checking whether it's the solution to this that is wrong or my own crap that's broken again, thanks